# MVC Html.ActionLink and Url.Action slow to render during Debug mode in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

**tl;dr** Displaying a view in MVC with lots of records and 4 rendered links per record takes a long time to load while running in debug mode in VS2012.

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 web application and one of the views displays a table of 300 records. Whenever I run the application in debug mode in VS2012, it takes nearly 2 minutes to load this view. The table has 4 unique links being generated either by HTML.ActionLink or URL.Action. From testing, I know the generation of these links is the offending code.

Example of slow code:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>Bob</td>
        <td>
    Tony
            <div style="margin-top: 5px;">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Home", new { id = item.Id })" class="btn btn-mini" title="Edit"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Home", new { id = item.Id })" class="btn btn-mini" title="Details"><i class="icon-file"></i></a>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Home", new { id = item.Id })" class="btn btn-mini" title="Delete"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top: 5px;">
                @Html.ActionLink("Do Something", "SomeAction", "SomeController", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-success btn-mini", data_pe_type = "auto" })
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

If I modify the code and build the base part of the links outside the foreach, the time to load reduces to 15 seconds.

Example of faster code:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @{
        var editLink = Url.Action("Edit", "Home") + "/";
        var detailsLink = Url.Action("Details", "Home") + "/";
        var deleteLink = Url.Action("Delete", "Home") + "/";
        var saLink = Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController") + "/";
    }
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>Bob</td>
        <td>
    Tony
            <div style="margin-top: 5px;">
                <a href="@editLink@item.Id" class="btn btn-mini" title="Edit"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
                <a href="@detailsLink@item.Id" class="btn btn-mini" title="Details"><i class="icon-file"></i></a>
                <a href="@deleteLink@item.Id" class="btn btn-mini" title="Delete"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top: 5px;">
                <a href="@saLink@item.Id" class="btn btn-success btn-mini" data-pe-type="auto">Do Something</a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

I'm using IIS Express and have tested this in both IE10 and Chrome 27 on Windows 7. In Chrome I have IPv6 disabled. This only happens during debug. I also had a co-worker test the same code on their machine and they encounter the same problem.

I've solved the performance problem by moving the base link generation outside the foreach, but now would like to know why Debugging caused my original code to render so slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Caching is disabled with `Debug=true.` That will cause performance issues on many levels including route/action resolution, view/partial-view location resolution and parsing etc. Overall deploying application in Release mode (`Debug=false`) will improve performance **up  to 10 times**, especially for large loops used in views.